# Alternative for sessions in sharepoint

Tags: session

I have used some session variable in my project which are giving some serialization error after i enabled `spsessionstate`. Do we have any alternatives for sessions in sharePoint? I tried changing sessions to viewstate but the problem still persists as whatever we are using in sessions/viewstate has to be serializable.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

There is no alternative to session in SharePoint. You must decorate the class with `serializable` attribute to store in session or `ViewState`.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably choose cookies. If cookies are out of option for you, and if it is a single front end farm, you can try the site Property Bag. But as noted [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/sharepointdevelopmentlegacy/thread/7d4ed3c2-343b-4d0d-9b65-878ca786bbb8), the Property Bag is not really meant as a Session substitute, so you'll need to make sure that you use unique keys and remove the key value pairs when you are done with them.

Refer [Alternative to Session in SharePoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120245/alternative-to-session-in-sharepoint) and [Need an alternative to session variable across pages](http://forums.asp.net/t/1382911.aspx?Need+an+alternative+to+session+variable+across+pages)